# amdgpu suddenly stopped working and logging "Failed to export SMU metrics table!"

Tags: arch-linux, wayland, amdgpu

I've been experiencing a strange issue on my Linux machine where the HDMI output to my monitor will suddenly stop working, displaying "No HDMI signal." This happens randomly while I'm browsing the internet, playing games, and doing other tasks. When the issue occurs, the audio output will continue to work for a while and then stop as well. In addition, my keyboard becomes unresponsive, as indicated by the num lock and caps lock indicators not working.

The only solution I have is to turn the power off and then back on. However, this is a temporary fix as the issue eventually occurs again.
I also once waited for a night, but that wasn't helping.

What could be causing this issue? How should I go about debugging it? I am running KDE desktop environment (Wayland) on Arch Linux, using an AMD graphics card. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

### Update:

Interestingly, after some time waiting for it to happen again and reboot. I found out with systemd journal that it is likely a driver issue. However I don't exactly know what it is and what cause it, but I will look into that later.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the same issues on Fedora while running KDE and Wayland, too. For the time being I switched back to X.

Answer (score 0):

Did it just start happening out of nowhere or did you install something prior to the malfunctions? I’m thinking it might have to do with your drivers. Maybe try updating them. It’s weird that your keyboard also freezes when that happens but that’s my best guess. Try a different HDMI cable also. Try a different port, like a display port if you can. That’s what I would try off the top of my head. Linux can be tricky like that sometimes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't look like a driver issue. I am using Arch, my drivers are all up to date. And I tried a different HDMI cable but problem persists.